# Borel-Cantelli lemma variation

Tags: probability

Consider $(X_i)$ independent events such that $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty P(X_i) = \infty$

Let $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{1}_{X_i}$, then $\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}S_n} \to 1$ almost surely.

Do you have any ideas how to prove this? I've been thinkint about applying law of large numbers or usual Borel-Cantelli lemma, but I could not come up with anything.

Comment: $M_n= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (1_{X_i}-P(X_i))$ is a martingale. If you can show it converges a.s. you are done. At the moment I don't know why it converges.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to prove that random variable $T_n = S_n / E S_n$ converges to 1 in probability. Then it also would converge in distribution, and for sequence converging in distribution to any Dirac delta you have convergence almost surely.

Comment: @Esgeriath That is not true. Convergence in distribution to a degenerate r.v. only gives convergence in probability, not a.s. convergence.

Comment: This is theorem 2.3.9 of Durrett PTE 5e. I don’t think his proof is very well written, but it’s correct.

Comment: Thanks @geetha290krm, I messed it up. Probably I shouldn't try to be clever late at night...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1_{X_i} \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_i)$ where $p_i = P(X_i)$.

If we consider a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables $B_i$ where $P(B_i = 1)=p_i \in (0,1)$ then:

$$E[S_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i,\;\; Var[S_n]= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i) $$

For independent but *not* necessarily identically distributed random variables, the following [version of the strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) holds:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}Var[B_i] < \infty \implies \bar{B}_n-E[\bar{B}_n] \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$$

Where $\bar{B}_n := \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n B_i$ (sample average).

Since $0<Var[B_i] < 1$ we know that:

$$0<\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}Var[B_i] < \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty$$

Therefore,

$$\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n B_i - \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$$

If $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i}{n} \to p$ ([Cesaro convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)) and $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i > 0\;\forall n$ then :

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n B_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i} - 1 \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0 \implies \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n B_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i} \xrightarrow{a.s.} 1$$

Stated more suggestively,

$$\frac{S_n}{E[S_n]} \xrightarrow{a.s.} 1\;\;\square$$

Comment: Thank you, I really like this idea, that we can think about indicators as Bernoulli distribution.